# Creating a vlookup formula with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have the following VBA code (a loop):

```
For i=1 to 20
Range("K" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[1],Database!R2C1:R10000C2,2,FALSE)"
Next i
```

I would like to make the second argument (the table where the value is taken from) more dynamic.

Suppose in the very beginning of the code I have:

```
Dim MyLookupRange as Range
Set MyLookupRange = Sheets("Database").Range("A2:B10000")
```

How can I use MyLookupRange as the second argument in my vlookup formula in my loop?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tecnically in your loop you could use something like this:

```
For i = 1 To 20
    Range("K" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[1]," & MyLookupRange.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True) & ",2,FALSE)"
Next i
```

Then again there is no need for a loop. Something like this should suffice:

```
Range("K1:K20").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[1]," & MyLookupRange.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True) & ",2,FALSE)"
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you, it works! Yes, a loop is not needed here, but in my case there is also an if statement which checks if the cell is empty. So it inserts the formula only for some values of i.